# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.example.bosco.utils.NBioBSPJNI.NBioAPI_NativeInit

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.example.bosco.utils.NBioBSPJNI.NBioAPI_NativeInit(com.example.bosco.utils.NBioBSPJNI, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_example_bosco_utils_NBioBSPJNI_NBioAPI_1NativeInit and Java_com_example_bosco_utils_NBioBSPJNI_NBioAPI_1NativeInit__Lcom_example_bosco_utils_NBioBSPJNI_2Ljava_lang_String_2) - is the library loaded, e.g. System.loadLibrary?

After fixing issues in the extracted fingerprint.jar file, the app crashes at runtime with an unspecified error. More details about the error message and context are needed for further assistance.